# Web Scraping Box Office Mojo with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data from BoxOfficeMojo for a Data Science project. I made some changes to this code I found from an already existing GitHub repository to suit my needs.

https://github.com/OscarPrediction1/boxOfficeCrawler/blob/master/crawlMovies.py

I need some help regarding scraping a particular feature. 
While I can scrape a movie gross normally, Box Office Mojo has a feature where they show you the Inflation-adjusted gross (The gross of the movie if it released in any particular year). The inflation-adjusted gross comes with an additional "&adjust_yr=2018" at the end of the normal movie link.

For example -

Titanic Normal link (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=titanic.htm)

Titanic 2018 Inflation adjusted link (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=titanic.htm&adjust_yr=2018)

In this particular code I linked earlier a table of URLs is created by going through the alphabetical list (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm ) and then each of the URLs is visited. The problem is, the alphabetical list has the Normal links of the movies and not the inflation-adjusted links. What do I change to get the inflation-adjusted values from here?

(The only way I could crawl all the movies at once is via the alphabetical list. I have checked that earlier)

Comment: You should check scrapy: https://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be simply to generate all the necessary url's by appending the list of normal urls with "&adjust_yr=2018" and scraping each site.

I personally like to use xpath (a language to navigate html structures, very useful for scraping!) and recommend not using string matches to filter out data from HTML as [it was once recommended to me](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156350/parsing-wikipedia-table-with-python). A simple way to use xpath is via the lxml library.

```
from lxml import html
    <your setup>
    ....

for site in major_sites:

    page = 1
    while True:
        # fetch table
        url = "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=" + site + "&p=.htm&page=" + str(page)
        print(url)
        element_tree = html.parse(url)
        rows = element_tree.xpath('//td/*/a[contains(@href, "movies/?id")]/@href')
        rows_adjusted = ['http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + row + '&adjust_yr=2018' for row in rows]

        # then loop over the rows_adjusted and grab the necessary info from the page
```

If you're comfortable using the pandas dataframe library I would also like to point out the pd.read_html() function, which, in my opinion, is predestined for this task. It would allow you to scrape a whole alphabetical page in almost a single line. Plus you can perform any necessary substitutions / annotations afterwards columnwise.

One possible way could be this.

```
import pandas as pd
    <your setup>
    ....

for site in major_sites:

    page = 1
    while True:
        # fetch table
        url = "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=" + site + "&p=.htm&page=" + str(page)
        print(url)

        req = requests.get(url=url)
        # pandas uses beautifulsoup to parse the html content
        content = pd.read_html(req.content)

        # chose the correct table from the result
        tabular_data = content[3]

        # drop the row with the title
        tabular_data = tabular_data.drop(0)

        # housekeeping renamer
        tabular_data.columns = ['title', 'studio', 'total_gross', 'total_theaters',
                                'opening_gross', 'opening_theaters', 'opening_date']

        # now you can use the pandas library to perform all necessary replacement and string operations
```

Further resources:
[Wikipedia has a nice overview of xpath syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Comment: I will try both the solutions and update the question. Thanks for helping me out.